# update json string in scala using jackson

Tags: json, scala, jackson, fasterxml

I have a json

```
val nodeJson =
      s"""
       {
          "NAME":"node1",
          "CONFIG":{
          "colMap": {
              "idcols": [
                  
                 ],
                 "emailcols":[
                 ]
             },
             "col.partitions": "3"
          }
       }
       """
```

I have to populate "idcols" and "emailcols" array dynamically from scala array.

like if i have arrays:

```
val idcols = Array("per_id","dep_id")
val emailcols = Array("per_email","dep_email")
```

then these values need to set in the json string

I have to use `com.fasterxml.jackson` library.

I am able to get the arrays:

```
val obj = new ObjectMapper()
  val root = obj.readTree(nodeJson)
  val value = root.get("CONFIG").get("colMap")
  println(value)
```

But I am not sure how to update it and set it back to the json. Kinldy let me know how can i update the json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jackson you most mutators are not defined on `JsonNode` but rather the specific sub-classes for that type of node (in your case `ArrayNode` for json arrays)

For example to add a string to the `idCols` array you would:

```scala
root.get("CONFIG").get("colMap").get("idCols").asInstanceOf[ArrayNode].add("someArbitraryString")
```

If you prefer more type safety (at the performance cost of allocating an extra case class) you could also consider creating a case class matching the structure of your document, parsing the json into that, updating the scala case class and serializing back to a json string.